# Red5 failed while installing Red5 application generation 1.0

Tags: java, eclipse, red5

I get this message: "failed while installing Red5 application generation 1.0" after setting up a new project in Eclipse.  I have it pointed at the right folder and I also have the newest Eclipse IDE with Java EE.  In addition here is my Java environment: 
java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Are you using the Red5 plugin for Eclipse?

Comment: yes I am using the Eclipse plugin.

Comment: I'll let the one of our team responsible for the plugin know about this post; in the interim, I suggest posting the issue here: https://github.com/Red5/red5-eclipse-plugin/issues

Comment: Managed to solve or is in trouble? I also have the same thing, but in windows environment.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this? I am facing same issue in windows environment..